# Use enum as dictionary key in delegate methods

Tags: swift, dictionary, key

I currently have messaging between an iOS app and WatchOS app happening. I am using a hardcoded string of message for the key. This works, but I want to have several types of messages. So I made an enum with type of String.

```
enum DeviceMessage: String {
    case Foo, Bar
}
```

In a view I want to call the WCSession send a message using my own method:

```
func sendMessage(msg:[String : Any]){
    if self.session.isReachable == false {
        self.session.transferUserInfo(msg)
    } else {
        self.session.sendMessage(msg, replyHandler: nil){ error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

**Instead of String for the dictionary key**, I want to be able to use .`Foo`. Without using `RawValue`, etc. What is the best way to set this up? In this vein, I would also like to set my delegate method for incoming messages to use DeviceMessage as a key too so I can evaluate it without using hardcoded strings for the keys.

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {
    print(message)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.message = userInfo["message"] as? String ?? "Unknown"
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why the key of the dictionary is String and not the enum? Any reason why the value of the dictionary is Any instead of String?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the file where my enum lives:

```
func DeviceMessageRawKey(key: DeviceMessage) -> String { return key.rawValue }
```

So now I can send and receive using String (no changes) but when being specific, I can use the enum.

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let val = message[DeviceMessageRawKey(key: .Foo)] {
            self.message = val as? String ?? "Unknown"
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
self.model.sendMessage(msg: [DeviceMessageRawKey(key: .Foo) : "Need data."])
```

Comment: How is `DeviceMessageRawKey(key: .Foo)` easier than `DeviceMessage.Foo.rawValue` ?

Comment: It looks a lot nicer in my opinion. If there is a way to do it without .rawValue hanging all over the place I would be interested.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing required for something to be a dictionary key is that it implements the `Hashable` protocol. Since your enum has a raw value of type `String`, you can just have it conform to the protocol and not implement anything.

```
enum DeviceMessage: String, Hashable {
    case Foo, Bar
}
```

You can then do:

```
let dict: [DeviceMessage: Any] = [.Foo: "hello"]
```

You will still need to convert from `[String: Any]` -> `[DeviceManager: Any]` (and vice versa) somewhere, but at least you can work with just `[DeviceManager: Any]` outside of the class that sends/receives messages.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to define a dictionary using a String enum as a key:

```
enum DeviceMessage: String {
    case Foo, Bar
}


var aDict: [DeviceMessage: String]

aDict = [.Foo: "woof"]
```

That works just fine. However, WatchKit's `sendMessage()` method wants the message to be of type `[String: Any]`.

You will need to convert your `[DeviceMessage: String]` dictionary to a `[String: Any]` dictionary to pass it to `sendMessage()`.